# ¿Qué significa esta declaración en TypeScript?

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Realizando mi aplicación en Nodejs y TypeScript, me aparece este error:

> src/managers/DucksManager.ts:55:7 - error TS2322: Type
> 'IDuckPosition[]' is not assignable to type '[IDuckPosition]'.
> Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.

¿Qué significa el tipo [IDuckPosition]?

Me aparece al realizar este código:

```
let posiciones: IDuckPosition ={
        duckId:newDuck._id,
        positionDate: newDuck.createdDate,
        lat: (await currentCampaign).launchZone[0].lat,
        lon: (await currentCampaign).launchZone[0].lon,
      };
      console.log("POSICIONES: ------------------------" +posiciones.lat + "-----------"+posiciones.lon);
      let arregloPosiciones: IDuckPosition[];
      arregloPosiciones.push(posiciones);
      console.log(arregloPosiciones);
      newDuck.throws = {arregloPosiciones[0]};
```

Es evidente que se trata de tipos no compatibles, pero ¿qué tipo es [IDuckPosition]? ¿Cómo se haría una declaración con este tipo de variable? Seguro que es una cosa muy sencilla, pero me estoy volviendo loco intentando dar con una solución.

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Podrías intentar crear otro tipo para el array y extender de `Array`, algo como `interface IDuckPositionItems extends Array<IDuckPosition>{}`. Luego bastaría con declarar tu array como ` let arregloPosiciones: IDuckPositionItems;`.

Comment: He intentado replicar el problema con tu código original y el único detalle/error que he visto es que TS dice que estas usando `arregloPosiciones` antes de ser asignado. Entonces también podrías intentar inicializar la variable como un arreglo vacío: `const arregloPosiciones: IDuckPosition[] = [];`

Comment: Gracias. Ahora voy  a seguir vuestras indicaciones. Un saludo

Comment: Aparte del problema de falta de inicialización del Array, esta linea: `newDuck.throws = {arregloPosiciones[0]};` es incorrecta. La sintaxis de esta asignación es errónea. Toma en cuenta que el primer elemento de tu `array` no está definido, pero en caso de que lo estuviera sería un objeto, por lo cual estarías haciendo esto: `newDuck.throws = { { ... } };` que claramente está mal. Para poder ayudarte hace falta que muestres cómo está definido `newDuck` y de qué tipo es la propiedad `throws`. Saludos